# Reduce multiclass to binary classification problem

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm doing an experiment with the well known [UCI heart disease dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+Disease) but it's not showing good results (~58% acc.).

This dataset has 5 ordinal classes with "levels of heart disease presence" going from 0 to 4, where 0 means *no heart disease* and 4 indicates *high presence of heart issues*. The problem is that this dataset is very unbalanced, and there are much more objects classified as 0 than the others. Present this dataset to a MLP has given 58% of accuracy, which is very low.

So, i'd like to combine all objects classified from 1-4 and transform this into a binary classification (e.g. 0 = no disease / 1 = disease found). I've noticed that this is known as `one-against-all`strategy. Since i'm very new to this world of ML, i'd like to know how could this be done with pandas or if there is a better tool for that.

Comment: `df['disease_found'] = df['level_presence'] > 0`, then use the "disease_found" column instead of "level_presence".

Comment: Not that I think this is the way out of your low accuracy problem. The bias is inherent to the data, and you should find an algorithm that suits your data, not fit your data to suit your algorithm.

Comment: Actually, i'm comparing a MLP to a Adaboost (ensemble) with Decision Trees. Both are giving this low accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple, currently your `y_train` data looks like: `[1,2,5,2,1,3,2,4,4,4,5,5,5]`
what you do is you create an empty array `binary_labels`, then iterate through each row in the PD, if the label is 1-4 you append 0 to binary_labels, else you append 1. Then you introduce a new column to the PD and set binary_labels against its values or you replace the y_train data with this array.

Also, you would replace the loss function in the MLP, etc. But this is how you structure the data.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by replace the loss function in the MLP? I am using standard `MLPClassifier` from `scikit-learn`

Comment: Thanks, my model is now with ~83% accuracy :D

Comment: oh i think the MLP infers the loss function, so thats okay :)